# How to use variables in a feature file, in a javascript function?

Tags: karate

For example i do

`* def fooresponse = call read('../getfooid.feature')`

`* def jsfunction= """(fooresponse){
        console.log(fooresponse)}"""`

is that possible? what is the recommended way to do it?

Thanks!

edit: fixing js syntax lol

Comment: also as a follow up question, is it possible to give values to a `karate.call()`just like we do it with `call read`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this will work if the function has been defined after the variable `fooresponse`:

```
* def jsfunction = function(){ karate.log(fooresponse) }
```

Yes, you can pass a single argument to `karate.call()`.

Keep in mind that the `#(foo)` substitution does NOT apply to pure-JS, explained here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-expressions

I think once you read the above link AND if you are familiar with JS, you will know what to do.

Like this:

```
* def fun = function(){ karate.call('foo.feature', { bar: 'baz' }) }
```

Comment: what i mean was with `call read(../something.feature)` we can pass in arguments like so `{id : '#(response.id)'}`, i was wondering if i can use the same curly braces style with a js function.

i went through the following documentation

https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/hooks/hooks.feature

but it doesnt really show an example of passing values like we do in a call read

Comment: thank you though it works. i will read the documentation more and more